# Как подключить бд ms sql server к приложению на flutter

Tags: сервер, flutter

База данных полностью готова, с запросами, лежит на рабочем столе. Ее надо подключить к приложению, написанному на flutter. Чтобы пользователи могли вытаскивать от туда информацию. Вопрос, как это сделать? Какой яп использовать? Есть ли какие-то курсы, наработки?

Comment: Ms sql - это серверная бд. Используйте sqlite для встраивания

Answer (score 1):

**Вопрос, как это сделать?**

Руками и головой.

**Какой яп использовать?**

В Flutter основным языком является Dart, также вы можете использовать нативные языки (такие как Kotlin & Swift) для написания нативных плагинов.

**Есть ли какие-то курсы, наработки?**

На счет курсов не уверен, но наработки точно есть. Вот одна из них: для получения данных с БД обычно использую [API](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST). Посредством API запросов мы обращаемся к базе данных и получаем обработанные данные, также мы можем отправлять в нее данные.

А если вы хотите использовать БД локально, то вам придется использовать [SqfLite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) или другие NoSql подобные базы данных.